# XPath / XSLT: How to nest siblings until a specific sibling into a new element?

Tags: html, xslt, xpath

I have the following HTML fragment:

```
<p>
    This is
    <font>start</font>
    just some <i>happy</i> text
    <font>stop</font>
    that might continue here.
</p>
```

and I want to use XSLT to turn it into this:

```
<p>
    This is
    <hi>
       just some <i>happy</i> text
    </hi>
    that might continue here.
</p>
```

so that everything (nodes and text and comments) between a font[text() = "start"] and a font[text() = "stop"] is nested within a new hi-element.

I tried:

```
<!-- identity template here-->

<xsl:template match="font[text()='start']">
    <xsl:element name="hi">
       <!-- FOLLOWING:SIBLING UNTIL THE NEXT font[text()='stop'] -->
       <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling[????]"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="font[text()='stop']"><!-- do nothing--></xsl:template>
```

but the ???? is where I couldn't find the right rule. I played around for half an hour, then I thought that asking might be faster.

It's important that its precisely to the next stop, as there might be numerous such constructions in one p element.

Thanks

Comment: It depends very much on whether you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. In 2.0 you can use `xsl:for-each-group`, in 1.0 you''ll have to use sibling recursion which is quite tricky. It also depends on whether you can have multiple start/end pairs within a paragraph, and on what you want to do if they aren't correctly paired. Please, with XSLT questions, always say which version you require.

Comment: Thanks,  it is XSLT 2.0 and there can be multiple pairs within one p but the start-stop flags can (as far as I've assessed the dataset) not be nested within another start-stop range. The for-each-group might be what I am looking for, but I couldn't yet figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="font[.='start']">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="font[.='end']">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="current-group()[self::font[.='start'] and self::font[.='end']">
      <hi>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(self::font)]"/>
      </hi>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </
  </
</
```

Not tested.